# How to speed up SolverManager.solveAndListen

Tags: performance, optaplanner

Every time I run `solverManager.solveAndListen(...)` to start OptaPlanner, it takes upwards of `500ms` to initialize it, and the actual solving starts after that.

Is there any way to dramatically speed this up? I ran a benchmark on it, but I'm not sure where it's spending all its time.

I'm doing `CVRPTWPD` and currently testing `3 Vehicles` with `167 Visits`, but lowering the `Visits` seems to have no impact, so it's got to be something else.

It's okay for my scenario if the first call to `solveAndListen` is slow, but I need subsequent calls to be very fast (under `30ms` would be ideal).

Thanks

***Edit:

I run the following code once:

```
solverConfig = SolverConfig.createFromXmlResource("solverConfig.xml") // takes 315ms
solverManager = SolverManager.create(solverConfig, SolverManagerConfig()) // takes 1409ms
scoreManager = ScoreManager.create(solverManager) // takes 556ms
```

Then I run a method many times which:

1. Loads/resets the entities (used by `this::findById`)
2. Runs this (I wrapped it in a timer), which takes ~500ms each time:

```
solverManager.solveAndListen(
            1,
            this::findById,
            this::save
        )
```

Comment: Are you using scoreDrl or constraintStreams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible culprits:

- The solverAndListen() transfers to a solver thread for the solver thread pool. But 500ms is unlikely to be here.
- The solver thread calls `SolverFactory.createSolver()`. Creating the solver isn't as fast yet as it could be (although in optaplanner 8.0 we had API changes that allow us to internalize the solver config now, we still don't do it yet.)
- Actual solving start: first from scratch score calculation, first planning clone, etc.

I would bet on the 2th item. Especially if you use scoreDRL, then it would parse the scoreDRL every time and build  Drools KieBase every time, which is expensive.

Comment: Interesting. I'm using constraintStreams. I call ```SolverFactory.createSolver()``` once beforehand, which does take time, but after that it's when I call ```solveAndListen``` multiple times where it's always a ~500ms delay each time. I can see my ```ConstraintProvider.defineConstraints``` run in there, but it's only about 1ms. Perhaps it's your #3 suggestion, but how would I optimize that and should it really be taking half a second?

Comment: With benchmarking, I found the call taking up 99% of the time: org.drools.ancompiler.KieBaseUpdaterANC.generateAndSetInMemoryANC so maybe it was your second suggestion after all. Any ideas on how to speed this up or at least cache it somehow?

Comment: Interesting observation. Please create a jira - the SolverFactory should cache the ANC work. That's non-trivial.

Comment: Thanks, I created one. I'm not sure if I classified it properly or explained it well, but it'd be a great enhancement for performance: https://issues.redhat.com/projects/PLANNER/issues/PLANNER-2621

Comment: I had a thought: doesn't this mean OptaPlanner is less practical for interacting with a UI in real-time? Eg. if I click something in a web application UI to alter the problem state, a web request goes through to OptaPlanner and solving begins, but this introduces a 500ms delay on top of the solving time. That's pretty substantial, but maybe I'm misunderstanding it and there's a different way to remove that 500ms additional delay?

Comment: Thanks for creating the issue. I think ANC can be disabled (lukas will know). Also, reusing a Solver actually works - even though we don't like that - but really, the SolverFactory should cache the ANC work: that is the real fix.

Comment: I suppose most people are running the solver for minutes at a time. However, I'm trying to reduce my CVRPTWPD problem to run in under 300ms so that I can run it repeatedly (1000's of times) with different scenarios for business projections. Getting it that fast is not easy! I'm getting close, but my custom moves are crazy at this point. Thanks - I look forward to the update and/or ANC disabling feature.

Comment: We should be able to optimize this on the OptaPlanner side. That said, two other comments. First, if you're looking to minimize your startup times, you should be looking into OptaPlanner+Quarkus - my bet is that this problem will not happen there at all. Second, even after we optimize this, the solver is still not likely to give decent results in milliseconds; I'd rethink the expectations here.

Comment: In optaplanner-quarkus, does the ANC optimizations for ConstraintStreams happen at build time, just like the gizmo reflection optimizations? That would make a big difference indeed in Solver creation time.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly when they happen.